# Default settings for http inbound gateway header mapping

Tags: spring-integration

I have an application which has many int-http inbound-gateways. I now have a requirement to  map a non-standard header from an http request. I know I can use `mapped-request-headers` to select which headers to be mapped, which is what I'm currently doing.

The problem is, dealing with all these gateways, I'll need to update each one to use the correct mappings. And furthermore the header should change (coming from a 3rd party), I would need to update ALL the gateways.

Is there a global setting for the inbound gateways where I can set the default mappings? This way I'd only need to change one setting and all the gateways would be updated.

A possible solution would be to implement `DefaultHttpHeaderMapper`, but is there an alternative (easier) method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is a problem to get ALL headers from request? 
In this case it's just enough to have this attribute for all your gateways:

```
mapped-request-headers="*"
```

With that there is no need to change anything in your app when third-party headers will be changed.

From other side just configure `DefaultHttpHeaderMapper` bean and refer to it from (again) each gateway using `header-mapper` attribute.
In this case you can change a set of `inboundHeaderNames` in any time (even at runtime) for that bean

Comment: I think this is what I'll need to do, but I was hoping there was a way I could set a value that would apply to ALL gateways without assing the mapped-request-headers field.